# terminal commands for brave browser after install

Tags: command-line, software-installation

0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,692 B of archives.
After this operation, 153 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]

Yes, I do want to continue......how do I confirm this? What is the command please?
New to Linux. Thank you.

Comment: Press Y and then Enter or Return.

Answer (score 0):

Press Y

It means yes you want to continue. Or next time whenever you run command, pass -y flag to automatically continue with yes.